How to access high quality and accurate company logo?
I'm working on my own full stack project and need to find an efficient way to get company logos through name search.
Right now I'm using Google Knowledge Graph(GKG) api but the issue is there are so many non-organization search result example result with GKG. And the search result is often not the logo but an image/icon related to search result: mis-aligned search result. What I want to achieve is something like Simplify's application record function here: Simplify application record, where the user can simply type in brand name and will be able to select from possible matches.
Another thing that I looked at is Clearbit Logo Api/Logo.dev. But the issue is it requires user to input the exact company domain, which might be too cumbersome.
Does anyone know any source I can look into? Thanks in advance!

Wikidata has the logo of most big companies, in each item's "logo image" property (also called P154 property).
Example:
https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q385775

Free open data.
Usually SVG format which means high quality at any scale.
Search API example: https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&format=json&errorformat=plaintext&language=en&uselang=en&type=item&search=oracl
That gives you different things that have that name, for instance Oracle Corporation (USA), Oracle Financial Services (India), etc. I is not super-fuzzy though. You can choose either the first match or another you prefer, then get the P154 property using the Wikibase API.
I have not tried it but the SPARQL API also seems to be able to do fuzzy search: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53987133/226958

Thanks! May I ask do you know if wikidata supports (fuzzy) search through company name?

Try https://logosear.ch/, or https://bimi-explorer.svg.zone/bimi/ from the same developer.
Alternatively, go to https://logo.synthfinance.com/ and add the company name or acronym, e.g.,
https://logo.synthfinance.com/ge .
Regarding that site, this thread on X/Twitter mentions a user who was ...

Looking to pay someone to format thousands of logos as icons for use in @maybe
and @synth_finance
.

original "invitation to tender" on X
Then:

tl;dr We paid a designer ~$70,000 to create some 14,000 stock market  icons for us (think AAPL, VTI, SPY, etc). We've only received ~1,500 of them and he's now ghosting us.

This is a long thread, and the logos   ended up as part of their free logo API on @synth_finance and in the comments many sites are mentioned that also offer free logos.

Actually, I contacted one developer of Logo.dev and they have an experimental API for brand domain search as shown in this site.
Also according to this article and comments below, Klazify and CUFinder are two possible alternatives. But I didn't try them myself.
